# Can I migrate a clone of Google Code repository into Github?

Tags: git, github, mercurial

I want to create a clone of a Google Code repository, which I cannot download due to Country restrictions and I want to migrate that clone into Github, which I can use without any problem.

The thing is I have a Github account and I can browse through GoogleCode but I cannot take my TortoiseHg and clone a repo just like that because I'm from Cuba and I get a lovely Google page saying that I cannot go into Google code.

I'm guessing you know [how I manage to browse](http://www.google.com/search?q=web%20proxy) :)

I would like to import a mercurial repository into my Github repo, my questions:

- **Is it possible?**
- **How can I do it?**

Comment: Can you sign up for a shell account in the united states?

Comment: Tell how do I do that and I'll tell you if I can... but I'm guessing no already...

Comment: Well go to dreamhost.com or somewhere similar and sign-up for a hosting account. If you can shell into that account you can do anything from it, such as retrieve the source from Google and either host it yourself on that account or push it up to your github repo.

Comment: Thanks for the advice jeremy, but can't use paypal either....

Comment: One way to do this (which admittedly loses the project history) is to download a tar.gz of current/latest of the project and use that as your starting point for your github.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Github does support importing directly from subversion. If your project was in SVN you could be able to import without country restrictions. It is explained here:

https://github.com/blog/156-subversion-importing

As for mercurial import in the same fashion, I can't find any resources. The github support knowledge base are redirecting directly to the contact form. It seems that a migration is being done right now.

But you can always ask someone to do the import for you.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't *directly* answer the question, but...

The easiest way is probably to get in touch with the developer/maintainer of the project and explain your situation -- with a little luck they will be able to provide some alternate means of access for you.

Comment: @Jhon, I tried contacting the repo owner but seems that he didn't *received* the mail :)

Comment: @David: I'm sorry to hear that. I hope Irae's answer lead you to a working solution.